# ¿Cómo obligo al usuario a introducir x limite de caracteres?

Tags: c#, caracteres, textbox

Quiero que el usuario ingrese 8 caracteres y si ingresa menos, mande una excepción.
En las propiedades del botón puse MaxLenght  = 8 para que no ingrese mas de 8 caracteres.
Intente con una condición si txtNumero.MaxLength < 8 mande una excepción, pero no me manda la excepción, y el catch es por si escribe letras mande error

```cs
      try
            {
                if (txtNumero.MaxLength < 8)
                {
                    throw new FormatException(MessageBox.Show("El numero debe tener 8 valores").ToString());
                }

                usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
                numero = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumero.Text);
                ClssEntrar objEntrar = new ClssEntrarex(usuario,numero);

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");

            }
```

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje?

Comment: Hola, estoy utilizando c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las **excepciones** no se usan así, de hecho deben usarse lo menos posible ya que su ejecución provoca una interrupción en el flujo del programa.

Usar **excepciones** conlleva responsabilidad y saber lo que se está haciendo, no es usarla por usarlas.

Las **excepciones** se usan para detectar en tiempo de ejecución, errores inesperados, errores que se salen de las validaciones hechas por el programador, por ejemplo una falla en la conexión con una base de datos.

Tu ejemplo se resuelve con validaciones:

```
if(txtNumero.MaxLength < 8)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
else
{
   usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
   //Resto del código
}
```

Se pregunta si el tamaño del texto es menor a **8**, de serlo se muestra un mensaje, de no serlo se continúa con la ejecución normal del código.

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, entonces el try catch solo lo usaría para validar que los valores estén correctos?, por ejemplo int num no reciba un valor de tipo string y mande error, y ya que se valide y no produzca un error, de ahí hacer mis validaciones por ejemplo que num deba tener 3 dígitos para seguir con la ejecución del programa

Comment: La excepcion la podrias dejar para que numero no convierta letras, ej no convierta a numero la cadena "aaa", aunque hay otras formas de lograr esto. Mi consejo es valida lo mas q puedas y deja las excepciones para casos específicos. Si mi respuests te fue util te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada

Comment: Si mi respuesta te ayudo te agradeceria q la marcaras como aceptada