# ¿Se puede hacer para que solo me abra archivos .cs?

Tags: c#

Quiero abrir solo archivos de cs pero si se abre un archivo que no sea cs mande una excepción, pero al abrir un archivo que no es cs, como una imagen me aparecen caracteres especiales y no la excepción

```
try
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = objArchivoCodigo.LeerArchivos(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }

    objArchivoCodigo.BuscarPalabras(richTextBox1.Text);
    listBox1.DataSource = objArchivoCodigo.Palabras;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Ahí no estás validando la extensión y tampoco sabemos qué hace el método LeerArchivos

Comment: Cual es la pregunta? porque si cambio la extension de cualquier archivo a .cs lo va a abrir. Que estas buscando en realidad?

Comment: Que solo abra archivos con extensión .cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atendiendo a lo que tienes ya hecho puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   var extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

   if(extension == ".cs")
   {
      richTextBox1.Text = objArchivoCodigo.LeerArchivos(openFileDialog1.FileName);        
      objArchivoCodigo.BuscarPalabras(richTextBox1.Text);
      listBox1.DataSource = objArchivoCodigo.Palabras; 
   } 
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Esta extensión no es la deseada");
   }  
}
```

Abrimos el **openFileDialog** y capturamos la extensión del fichero que intentamos abrir, posteriormente preguntamos si es la extensión deseada, de serlo ejecutamos tu código y de no serlo ejecutamos un **MessageBox** alertando que el fichero no tiene la extensión deseada.

Para capturar la extensión del fichero usamos el **método** **GetExtension** de la **clase** **Path**. Para usar la **clase** **Path** debemos poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Esto no evita que abra otro tipo de archivos. Si cambia la extension, se van a abrir igual.... no creo que sea lo que esta preguntando OP.

Comment: @gbianchi, no abre otros ficheros, solamente abre los de extension .cs

Comment: @gbianchi, lo que solamente sabra el usuario que hace su metodo LeerArchivos, supongo que ponga en el textbox el contenido de estos ficheros

Comment: no. abre cualquier cosa que tenga extension .cs.. probalo.... el filesystemdialog solo aplica un filtro.. no chequea el contenido del archivo...

Comment: y por eso, le deje un comentario en la pregunta....

Comment: @gbianchi, pero si alguien cambio una extension de .doc a .cs es otra cosa, igualmente que pasa si el archivo esta corrupto, o cualquier otra condicion rara, me parece que estas buscando la pelusa de la contrapelusa, no hay q complicarse tanto la vida, si yo quiero hacer un programa y quiero que el usuario no le tire fotos a la pantalla pues podria deshabilitar la tecla printScreen, pero y si la persona le tira una foto con un celular, como yo valido eso?, no es pa tanto

Comment: @gbianchi pa hacer eso q pides tendria q meterme dentro del fichero, buscar en el encabezado del fichero que se yo, no creo q el usuario sea tan exquisito

Comment: No.. no le busco pelusa.. cuando op dice que quiere que le tire una excepcion, es por algo.. por eso, preferi preguntarle... y deje el mismo comentario en las dos respuestas...

Comment: @gbianchi, pues no creo, este usuario abusa de las excepciones creyendo que trabajan como las condiciones if, ya yo le expliqué una vez, pero parece que no comprendió del todo y sigue repitiendo lo mismo, entra aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460184/c%c3%b3mo-obligo-al-usuario-a-introducir-x-limite-de-caracteres para que veas de lo que hablo, sencillamente el usuario no está claro de cuando se deben usar las excepciones

Comment: Entonces, todavia mejor, preguntarle que quiere realmente... que se entienda que tu respuesta no esta mal.. solo que lo que logras es filtrar una lista.. no validar un tipo de archivo...

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

**Según la documentación de Microsoft openFileDialog tiene una propiedad para filtrar el tipo de archivo que vas a subir**

[Puedes revisar aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=net-5.0)

Así que una forma de hacer lo que quieres seria:

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Text files | *.cs"; // filtramos los tipos de archivos que se permitira cargar
        dlg.Multiselect = false; // validamos para que el usuario solo suba un archivo a la vez
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // 
        {
            String path = dlg.FileName; // obtenemos el nombre del archivo 
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), new UTF8Encoding()))
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Esto no evita que abra otro tipo de archivos. Si cambia la extension, se van a abrir igual.... no creo que sea lo que esta preguntando OP.